# Building a nested array with recursive function

Tags: php, algorithm

I got a JSON object like below which is pointing to a file structure. The objects that contain objects are folders, and others are files. And I'm downloading the contents in the URLs (The object can go much bigger or smaller.)

```
{
    "foo": {
        "bar": "https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/10/file_example_JPG_2500kB.jpg",
        "baz": "https://sample-videos.com/img/Sample-jpg-image-100kb.jpg",
        "caz": {
            "zaz": "https://sample-videos.com/img/Sample-jpg-image-100kb.jpg",
            "kaz": {
                "haz": "https://sample-videos.com/img/Sample-jpg-image-100kb.jpg"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I'm looping through that object and generating a unique id from each key-value pair.

This is the recursive function that loops over the object and generates unique ids

```
<?php

function myRecursiveFunc($obj, &$parentId = null, &$result = [])
{
    $result = [];
    $fileNames = array_keys($obj);

    foreach ($fileNames as $fileName) {

        if (is_array($obj[$fileName])) {

            $folderId = uniqueIdBuilder(); //Function that generate unique id

            buildResult($result, $parentId, $folderId, true); // The function to build $result object

            $parentId = $folderId;

            return myRecursiveFunc($obj[$fileName], $parentId, $result);
        } else {

            $url = $obj[$fileName];

            $fileId = uniqueIdBuilder($url);

            buildResult($result, $parentId, $fileId); // The function to build $result object
        
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Generating unique ids part is working. However, I want to build a result object to show generated unique ids with the exact file structure.

So the result object should look like this:

```
[
  'fooId' => [
    'barId',
    'bazId',
    'cazId' => [
        "zazId",
        "kazId" => [
            "hazId"
        ]
  ]
]
```

I have created the function that I will show below, but it does not work.

```
    function buildResult(&$result, $parentId, $fileId, $isFolder = false)
    {
        if (count($result) > 0) {
            foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
                if (is_array($value)) {

                    if($key === $parentId && !$isFolder)
                        return $result[$parentId][] = $fileId;
                        
                    if($key === $parentId && $isFolder)
                        return $result[$parentId][] = [$fileId => []];


                    buildResult($value, $parentId, $fileId);

                }
            }
        } else {
            $result[$parentId] = [];
        }
    }
```

The result doesn't have to look exactly like I mentioned above. The important thing for me is that this result object contains the generated unique ids.

I'm open to any advice and help

Edit:

I'm getting this result from `buildResult()`:

```
[
   "result" => [ "" => []]
]
```

Comment: Please clarify what `it does not work` means. What is the result you're currently getting from your code?